# Open a child div of parent that occurs multiple times

Tags: jquery, toggle, parent-child

I have multiple instances of a dropdown that I would like to open individually. The jQuery I have opens all toggles all of 'dropdown-content' on the page.

Is it possible to stop this and to have only the child div of each individual parent be toggled?

Here's my code:

```js
jQuery('.dropbtn').click(
  function() {
    jQuery('dropdown-content').toggle();
  });
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn most-left">Title</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<p>some text</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you select *all* `.dropdown-content` elements. To fix the issue use the `this` keyword within the click event handler to reference the `button` which was clicked. From there you can traverse the DOM to find the relevant div to toggle. You could use either `closest()` and `find()`, or `next()`. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.dropbtn').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.dropdown-content').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-content { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn most-left">Title</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn most-left">Title</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn most-left">Title</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```